# Difference between Camera/Eye coordinates and world coordinates

Tags: opengl, camera, coordinate-transformation

For the sake of simplicity let's take OpenGL rendering system as an example. According to what I have learnt,

The camera in OpenGL is aligned with the world space's origin i.e (0,0,0). I also read that we don't move the camera so it will stay at it's original position of (0,0,0) in world coordinates. The camera faces in the negative z direction.

Thus the question is, if **you don't move the camera then it will always stay at world space's origin of (0,0,0)**. If that's the case then there will be no difference between world and eye coordinates. Because for example, Object A position in world coordinates is (2,2,-5). In eye coordinates it will be the same `(2-0, 2-0, -5-0) = (2,2,-5)`

Comment: Why would you want to fix the camera in world space. It is always at the origin of the view coordinate system facing --z, but non of this is the case in world space.

Comment: @BDL From what i read on the internet, most applications set the default position of the camera to the world space's origin. Secondly you can't move the camera. If that's the case what's the difference between world and camera coordinate sytem?

Comment: For example this tutorial implements a movable camera in OpenGL (https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Camera). I don't know where you got your information from, but as I wrote above, there is absolutely no good reason why you shoudn't be able to move the camera.

Comment: @BDL- Now i am confused. Check these links
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40741/why-do-we-move-the-world-instead-of-the-camera

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Maybe you are talking about the 3d camera assosciated with the person? Are there different types of cameras?

Comment: In both links you provided is the concept of a view matrix explained, which transforms the world space into camera (or view) space. Changing this matrix is exactly the same as moving the camera (although the view-matrix is the inverse of the camera's model matrix). The world space is the space **before** applying the view matrix to it. You can either think of it as transforming the whole world around the camera in **view space** or as moving the camera in **world space**. But non of this articles states the the cameras location is fixed in world space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The camera is the eye. If you don't move your camera, it means that your View matrix is an identity matrix so any coordinate you multiply with it will remain the same.

Lets take your example, we have a point being rendered `(2.0, 2.0, -5.0)`. This is the world space position of the point. It means the point lies at `(2.0, 2.0, -5.0)` regardless of where the camera is.

If the camera is at origin like you say, yes the eye(camera) space position is the same as the world space position.

For a simple example, lets say you want to move your camera 2 units in the positive z-axis. Now your camera is at `(0, 0, 2)` and when you look from your camera(or eye), the point will be 2 units farther away in z axis from the origin, since you moved your camera back, so the eye space position is `(2.0, 2.0, -7.0)`.

This is what happens with more complicated transformation on your camera. You will have a view matrix which will just be the inverse of your camera's transformation, and this is applied to every point in world space to convert it to eye (or camera) space.